# How to make cross sign based on user-input in C

Tags: c

Hi i'm currently practicing using c in my school, i have a problem to make cross-sign in C based on user-input, my code only work properly when the height is 11
first i made non-user-input code when height=11 (well this is my actual assgnment) and then make some changes here and there
thanks for your answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
    int n, i = 1, j = 9, l = 0, height;
    char ch = '#';

    printf("Enter the height of cross sign : ");
    scanf("%d",&height);

    n = (height / 2.0) - 0.5;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        printf("%*c%*c\n", i, ch, (2*n - 2*i + 1), ch);
        i++;
    }
    while (n < j)
    {
        printf("%*c%*c\n", (j - n), ch, (j - n - 1 + l), ch);
        n++;
        l += 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code has some compiler error. You missed some semicolons. Secondly your code works fine till 11 cause of the CPL. You can read about it in the link given below :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_per_line

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to see where's the middle, if you have two variables doing the opposite, like one decreasing and the other increasing at the same time.

this is my code to that problem resolved:

```
int height, i , j, l;
char ch = '#', sp = ' ';

printf("Enter the height of cross sign : ");
scanf("%d",&height);

j=height;
for(i=1;i<=height;i++)
{
    for(l=1;l<=height;l++)
    {
        if(l==i||l==j)
        {
            printf("%c", ch); //if it's suppose to print '#'
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", sp); //if it's suppose to print space - ' '
        }
    }
    j--;
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: You are using a int variable when you are subtracting.